# Обработка спарсенных данных регулярнымим выражениями php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Парсю данные авиакомпаний с одного информационного ресурса. Не получается настроить шаблон регулярного выражения для поиска и замены некоторых данных. Вот пример спарсенной строки:

```
<pre>Страна:&nbsp;Украина
Чартерные бизнес-перевозки в Украине
Год образования:&nbsp;1997
Код ИАТА:&nbsp;DW
Код ИКАО:&nbsp;UCR
Официальный cайт авиакомпании:&nbsp;www.acr-air.com
Адрес:&nbsp;Украина, 03110, Киев, ул. Клименко 23
Телефон:&nbsp;+380 44 207 08 18
Факс:&nbsp;+380 44 207 08 19
E-mail:&nbsp;vip_charter@acr-air.com
Базовые аэропорты:&nbsp;Киев Борисполь, Киев Жуляны
Самолетный парк:&nbsp;Антонов Ан-26, Яковлев Як-40</pre>
```

я пытаюсь во первых достать Код ИАТА, т.е. две заглавные английские буквы. Во вторых засунуть названия свойств "Страна, Год образования и пр." в тег **...**.

Для поиска ИАТА кода пытался использовать такой шаблон *[A-Z]{2}?* - не помогло, точнее он возвращает не только ИАТА код, но и часть кода ИКАО и 2 буквы из e-mail адреса (регулярку проверяю тут http://www.pcre.ru/eval/).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте лучше вот в таком духе сделать:

```
$rules = [
    '(Страна):&nbsp;(.+)',
    '(Код ИАТА):&nbsp;([A-Z]{2})',
    '(Код ИКАО):&nbsp;([A-Z]{3})'
];

$pageData = [];

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    preg_match(sprintf('/%s/u', $rule), $rawString, $matches);
    if (count($matches) == 3) {
        $pageData[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
    }
}

print_r($pageData);
```

Где `$rawData` -- ваша портянка текста (без тэга `pre`). В `rules` указываете правила по разбору каждой нужной вам строки по отдельности. Обратите внимание на группировку. Первая группа становится ключом (названием параметра), а вторая -- его значение.

Почему так? На мой взгляд, в таком способе есть прозрачность. Очевидно, какое правило, за что отвечает. Легко исправлять и дополнять. Разумеется, прошу воспринимать мой код как идею (или намёк, как угодно), а не сырьё для копипаста в свой код ;)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую ))

Comment: @maler1988 ответ примете?)